# While condition in Python

Tags: python

```
# to find the cube root of a number
X = int(raw_input ('Enter an integer'))

ans = 0

while ans* ans*ans < abs(x):
    ans = ans + 1
    print 'current guess =', ans
```

Why do I get 'current guess' value up to 4, for say an integer input of 55. Shouldn't it stop at 3, since the while condition says - `ans*ans*ans` until the product is less than the integer you entered? 'current guess' of 4 means: `4*4*4 = 64` which is greater than 55 (the integer entered)

Comment: Note: `X` and `x` are not the same

Comment: consider this x and not X..

Comment: You should swap the lines within the loop.

Comment: Note that after checking the condition, at the top of the loop, you increment `ans` and then print it out, before the condition is checked again. So the number you print out is _not_ the same number that the `while` condition just checked.

Comment: Can someone explain me the while condition ?

Comment: thanks khelwood for pointing that out. makes sense! guys any idea how i could swap the lines so the condition is checked until the 3rd guess and then print it out as 3?

Answer (score 4):

You are incrementing before printing out the current guess.

**First pass:**

```
ans=0 (0); guess=0+1=1
```

**Second pass:**

```
ans=1 (1); guess=1+1=2
```

**Third pass:**

```
ans=2 (8); guess=2+1=3
```

**Fourth pass:**

```
ans=3 (27); guess=3+1=4
```

**Fifth pass:**

```
ans=4 (64) and loop condition no longer true
```

Comment: Got it now. Thanks EdC for clarifying!